# Xcode 6 Don't Apply Vibrant Effect to Child View

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode6, nsvisualeffectview

Good evening, everyone!

Is it possible to apply the "vibrant" visual effect to a parent view, without a child view inheriting it?

My main window has the vibrant effect applied to the entire view, but when using a popover segue to display a new view, that view is also transparent. Is there any way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the popover view's window appearance in the controller's `viewWillAppear()`:

**Swift**

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    self.view.window?.appearance = NSAppearance(named: NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark)
}
```

**Obj-C**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
  self.view.window.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @joshua ! Please forgive my ignorance, but I'm quite new to ObjectiveC, and have run into a few errors with the above code. I think my issues come down to me not really knowing where it's supposed to execute. Should I put it inside of `- (void) viewWillAppear`, or is it a function all on it's own? Sorry again, and thanks for your time.

Comment: -viewWillAppear is overridden in your NSViewController subclass that is responsible for your popover's view. It is called by the system after your view is loaded but before it is placed on screen. It's a great place to customize visual appearance. The examle I gave was in Swift.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never spent any time with Swift, and am not comfortable enough with Objective C to successfully convert it myself. In attempting to, I'm seeing a few errors, which I wonder if you'd be kind enough to help me with. Using `[self.view.window.appearance setCurrentAppearance:NSAppearanceNameAqua];`, I'm being told "No visible @interface for 'NSAppearance' declares the selector 'setCurrentAppearance:'". I understand this means it can't find the method setCurrentAppearance, which is confusing me, since it seems available on the NSAppearance Class Reference. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated my answer to include ObjC. Alternately you could use `[self.view.window setAppearance:...];` (example in answer uses dot notation; don't use `setPropertyName:` style setter when using dot notation in ObjC)